# template error - cannot be a template definition

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

I have created a simple LinkedList class using templates in C++

Basically I can create an instance of my list like this

```
LinkedList<int> myList = LinkedList<int>();
```

Now I would like to add a method to my LinkedList and provide a callback function so that function can call back to my code to perform an action.

I tried to create the following

```
template< typename T>
typedef bool(*LinkedList_SortCallBack2)(T);
```

But I receive a compiler error

**error C2998: 'bool (_*cdecl **_cdecl LinkedList_SortCallBack2)(T)' : cannot be a template definition**

as a work around I have used void * but is there a way to do what I want? so my call back is like this

```
bool cb(int NewValue, int ExistingValue)
{
}
```

instead of

```
typedef bool (*LinkedList_SortCallBack)(void *value1, void* value2);


bool cb(void* NewValue, void* ExistingValue)
{
    int a, b;

    a = *(int *)NewValue;
    b = *(int*)ExistingValue;
    if (a < b)
           return true;
    else
           return false;

}
```

Comment: Which version of the C++ standard are you relying on?  Before C++11 there were no typedef templates.  Even C++11 added alias declarators with `using` to enable that.

Answer (score 0):

Typedefs cannot be templates.

In C++11, use aliases

```
template <typename T>
using callback = void (*)(T);
```

In C++03, put it inside a structure

```
template <typename T>
struct SortCallback {
  typedef void (*)(T) type;
};
typename SortCallback<int>::type callback;
```